# How to call/use controller method in its View using Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I need to use my controller function in its own view.

I have tried Facade but failed.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22153332/2815635

Comment: I have tried to create custom helper class. I have register it with provider and create its facade but not working.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have also tried this link but not working.

Comment: I have use App::make("PostsController")->get_social_plans_data(1); with my controller name and method, but not working, 
should I need to include any file or library?

Comment: when I write the above code, this error is coming. Class PostsController does not exist (View: F:\wamp\www\kiosk_admin\resources\views\posts.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You want to use a function defined in a Controller in one of the views it is calling?

If that's your question you can do following, (I am assuming the function is public static function returning some string). In your blade view file you can just call the function using the full name space path.

`{{App\Http\Controllers\MyController::myFunction()}}`

(There are ways in blade to import a class using use statement)

It is **not recommended** to call functions defined in controller like this (its against MVC), you can define them in the Model or create a separate Helper class.