# Call a controller function into a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've got a Controller (UsersController) with a function :

```
 public function project_donated($project_id)
{
    return Donation
        ::groupBy('donations.project_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(donations.amount) as sum, donations.project_id, projects.*')
        ->where('donations.project_id', $project_id)
        ->join('projects', 'donations.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
}
```

This function works fine.

I return this function into the same UserController to my view with :

```
$project_donated = $this->project_donated($project_id);
return view('users.show', compact('user', 'countries', 'donation_user' , 'user_donated', 'project_donated'));
```

But, I cannot defind $project_id into my controller, I need to specify it into my view, so into my view, I had this line :

```
<?php
$project_id = $ngo->project->ngo->id;
$project_donated = UsersController::project_donated($project_id);
?>
```

But I've got an error : Class 'UsersController' not found.

I'm not sure I'm doing this the right way.

Comment: First of all, it should be `UserController`, not `UsersController`. Also, you're doing it all wrong, so recommend you to read Laravel docs first. At least read about controllers, routes and views.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking this is the wrong way. I'm taking back from someone else. But could you explain quickly what I'm doing wrong in this case ?

Comment: That's not how to use a controller. It shouldn't be called from inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the controllers from anywhere in the application. But it is not the general practice. Go through some general practices.

```
 App::make('controller name')->public_methodName(params);
```

Similar question has been raised in the following thread.

[How to call a controller from within a view - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151822/how-to-call-a-controller-from-within-a-view-laravel)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: So it's not a good practice to call a function directly into a view ?

Comment: Yes, when you are using an MVC framework, then its not a good practice to do some things that are against the rules of MVC

Comment: Yes. It is not the generally accepted practice plus it makes the life harder when it comes to modifications for the code.